# How do I get Django API JavaScript call to work

Tags: python, django

I am making a fake stock trading Django app. I am 99% sure that my file structure is correct. I get a 404 error from the JavaScript fetch:

> Not Found: /api/stock/IBM/
> [24/Oct/2023 19:09:52] "GET /api/stock/IBM/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2250

Could someone assist me?

I was expecting to get a live feed of the IBM stock. I would also like to make it customizable to any stock.  I am new to handling API.

Relevant Files

api_utils.py

```py
import requests

def fetch_intraday_data(symbol):
    API_KEY = 'HRUU8PUIVR7TPGIJ'  # Replace with your Alpha Vantage API key
    url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol={symbol}&interval=5min&apikey={API_KEY}'
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise HTTPError for bad responses (4xx and 5xx)
        
        data = response.json()
        
        # Check if Alpha Vantage returns an error message
        if "Error Message" in data:
            return {"error": data["Error Message"]}
        
        return data
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
```

views.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from stocktrading.api_utils import fetch_intraday_data
from django.http import JsonResponse

# replace the "demo" apikey below with your own key from https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key
# api = 'HRUU8PUIVR7TPGIJ'
# url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=api'
# r = requests.get(url)
# data = r.json()
# print(data)
# import datetime



class CreateAccountForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Username'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password Again", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Password Again'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User # Use Django's User model
        fields = ["username", "password1", "password2"] # Form fields

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CreateAccountForm, self).save(commit=False) # Get user object without saving to DB
        if commit:
            user.save()  # Save user to DB
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, balance=0.0) # Create user profile with initial balance
        return user

def home(request):
    return render(request, "stocktrading/home.html")

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        # If form is not valid, re-render the login page with the invalid form
        else:
            return render(request, 'stocktrading/login.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'stocktrading/login.html', {'form': AuthenticationForm()}) # If request method is not POST, display an empty login form (authentication form is just the form)


def createaccount(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateAccountForm(request.POST)  # req.post contains all of the data the user submitted
        if form.is_valid():  # check if user form is valid
            user = form.save()  # This will handle saving the user
            auth_login(request, user)  #login user to the account they just created
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created successfully!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home"))
        else:  # form wasn't valid
            return render(request, "stocktrading/createaccount.html", {  # return previous form (error messages are handled automatically)
                "form": form
            })

    return render(request, "stocktrading/createaccount.html", {
        "form": CreateAccountForm()
    })

def logout_view(request): #when logout is clicked, logout and send to homepage
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def stock_api_view(request, symbol):
    symbol = "IBM"
    stock_data = fetch_intraday_data(symbol)
    print("Fetched stock data:", stock_data)
    return JsonResponse(stock_data)

def stock_view(request):
    symbol = "IBM"
    stock_data = fetch_intraday_data(symbol)  # fetch_intraday_data is a function you've defined to get the data
    context = {'stock_data': stock_data}
    return render(request, 'stocktrading/stockview.html', context)
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name = "home"),
    path("login/", views.login_view, name = "login"),
    path("createaccount/", views.createaccount, name = "createaccount"),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('stocktrading/', views.stock_view, name='stocktrading'),
    path('api/stock/<str:symbol>/', views.stock_api_view)
]
```

stockview.html

```html
{% extends "stocktrading/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>


{% endblock %}
```

main.js

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Initialize the Chart
    let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Stock Price',
                data: []
            }]
        }
    });

    function fetchAndUpdate() {
        fetch('/api/stock/IBM/')
            .then(response => {
                // Check if the response is OK (status code 200-299)
                if (!response.ok) {
                    return Promise.reject('Fetch failed; HTTP status ' + response.status);
                }
                return response.json();  // Parse the JSON data
            })
            .then(data => {
                // Update the chart here.
                // Assume 'time' and 'price' exist in the data
                let newTime = data.time || 'Unknown Time';
                let newPrice = data.price || 0;
                
                myChart.data.labels.push(newTime);
                myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(newPrice);
                myChart.update();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // Handle errors
                console.error('Fetch Error:', err);
            });
    }

    // Fetch new data every 5 seconds
    setInterval(fetchAndUpdate, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

404 error means the URL you are calling is not found. Because you are using javascript separately to call the api and manually passing the url, it does not resolve the host component of the url automatically i.e. you are missing 'http:localhost:port' component of the url and your fetch call seems to be missing it. You can pass the url as part of the context when you render the template that holds the javascript and store the url for the api endpoint somewhere on the DOM (maybe attribute of button use to make the call) and extract from it.

In other words, your complete api url should be:

"http://localhost:8000/api/stock/IBM/. Replace 8000 with the port you are running the dev server on.